# Сайт freelance в Рунете

Tags: работа

Какой российский сайт фрилансеров по Вашему мнению лидирует в Рунете?
На каком сайте лично Вы фрилансите?
Каковы главные достоинства этого сайта?

Развернутые ответы приветствуются, ссылки мне и гугл может дать :)

Comment: Кто же выдаёт "рыбные" места? Да еще и рассказать, что да как :)

Comment: имхо в рунете фрилансят только новички или те кто очень давно во фрилансе и имеет хороший профиль с историей. А так делать тут нечего

Comment: @Barton- обычно новички начинают работать не за деньги, а за хорошую рекомендацию, при таком подходе путь во фриланс открыт.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

не реклама! я уже почти с самого открытия проекта [Фрилансим.ру](http://freelansim.ru) там сижу, разработал Хабрахабр

Comment: Ты разработал хабрахабр? Ггы =) Строй хотя бы предложения грамотно)

Comment: кстати хабрахабр это же livestreet движок


Answer (score -2):

free-lance.ru основные заказы у меня оттуда. Проектов там больше всего в Рунете для вебпрогера
freelansim.ru мониторю, но проектов там раз в 5 меньше и оттуда заказов у меня пока нет.

Answer (score -2):

Рунет — болото. Платят мало, требуют много.

При хотя бы зачаточном знании английского идти на зарубежные биржи: oDesk, Elance и др.

После обрушения рубля вопрос про выбор между российскими и зарубежными сайтами вообще вставать не должен.